# Build table body in php

Tags: php

I want to make a class that generated tables when necessary. What i want is to call a method like below:

```
$html = new HTML;
$html->createTbody(
  Array(
    'tr' => Array(
      'td' => Array(
        '1','2','3','4'
      )
    ), 
    'tr' => Array(
      'td' => Array(
        '5','6','7','8'
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Here for i have the following method:

```
<?php
Class HTML{

   [..]

  public function createTbody($params = Array()){
    $output = "\n\t".'<tbody>';  
    foreach($params['tr'] AS $tr){
      $output .= '<tr>';
      foreach($params['tr']['td'] AS $td){
        $output .= "\n\t\t".'<td>'.$td.'</td>';
      }
      $output .= '</tr>';
    }
    $output .= "\n\t".'</tbody>'."\n";
    echo($output);
  }
?>
```

The problem with this is, that only the last `tr` array is printed. Also when i `print_r` the `$params` array, it shows `5, 6, 7, 8`.

Now i'm pretty stuck. I assume i have to make the `tr` arrays unique or the method recursive, but how?

I tried calling the method like so:

```
$html->createTbody(
  Array(
    'num' => '2', 
    'tr1' => Array(
      'td' => Array(
        '1','2','3','4'
      )
    ), 
    'tr2' => Array(
      'td' => Array(
        '5','6','7','8'
      )
    )
  )
);
```

And then the same method within a `for($i=0;$i<$params['num'];$i++)` loop and call the `tr and td` arrays like `$params['tr'.$i]['td']` but that didn't output it the way it should. It did show the complete array when i printed that one though.

Can maybe anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are defining the same key over and over, and thus overwriting them.
I would advise you not to use keys at all. Just make sure the first level of the array is always tr's, and the second level always td's.

Also when printing out, you are doing the inner foreach wrong; you should use the tr variable from the first foreach, and get its tds, in stead of getting all tr's/td's on foreach tr's.

Furthermore you have one layer too much of arrays. The one you call TR always contains just 1 item.

This should suit better:

```
$html = new HTML;
$html->createTbody(
    Array( // entire table
        Array( // tr
            '1','2','3','4' // td's
        ), 
        Array( // tr
            '5','6','7','8' // td's
        )
    )
);
```

And this could be your output code:

```
<?php
Class HTML{

    [..]

    public function createTbody($params = Array()){
        $output = "\n\t".'<tbody>';  
        foreach($params AS $tr){
            $output .= '<tr>';
            foreach($tr AS $td){
                $output .= "\n\t\t".'<td>'.$td.'</td>';
            }
            $output .= '</tr>';
        }
        $output .= "\n\t".'</tbody>'."\n";
        echo($output);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
array(
    'tr' => array(
        array(1, 2, 3, 4), // first row
        array('foo', 'bar', 5, 6), //second row
        // ...
    ),
);
```

If you need to separate `td` from `th`, you can use something like:

```
array(
    'tr' => array(
        array('th' => array(1, 2, 3, 4), 'td' => array(5)), // first row
        array('td' => array('foo', 'bar', 5, 6, 7)), //second row
        // ...
    ),
);
```